# Django error with "STATIC" and reverse for 'register' not found

Tags: python, html, django, authentication, django-views

Hey guys a fellow Django developer here.
The static word is coming in red as an error. including the % and }

`<body id="bg" style="background-image: url({% static 'users/images/bg.png' %});">`

[Error recieved when server is running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjkn7.png)
[Errors recieved in Editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0Gf9.png)

**Base.html**

```
<!doctype html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--Css Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'users/static/css/main.css' %}" type="text/css">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Font Link-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&family=Open+Sans:wght@800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body id="bg" style="background-image: url({% static 'users/images/bg.png' %});">
  {% load static %}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" id="main-navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}"><img src="{% static 'images/in-logo-1.svg' %}" alt="" ></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Market</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Company</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Education</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resouces</a>

            </div>
            <form class="d-flex" id="authstyle">
              {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a href="{% url 'profile' %}" class="btn" style="color: white; background-color: #fd5e14;"type="submit" id="header-links"> Profile </a>
                <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="btn" style="color: white; background-color: #fd5e14;"type="submit" id="header-links"> Logout </a>
              {% else %}
                <a href="{% url 'register' %}" class="btn" style="color: white; background-color: #fd5e14;"type="submit" id="header-links"> Create Account </a>
                <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn" style="color: white; background-color: #fd5e14; margin-left: 10px; "type="submit" id="header-links">Log In</a>
              {% endif %}
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

      <div>
        <div class="container">
          {% if messages %}
          {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{message.tags}}">{{message}}</div>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
      </div>

      <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

      <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
      <!--
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Creating out view here
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'users/home.html')
```

**Home.html**
`{% extends 'users/base.html' %}`

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from users import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home')
]
```

**main.css**

```
#bg{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }
  #main-navbar{
    color: white;
    min-height: 14vh;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  #authstyle{
    margin-left: 17%;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  #header-text{
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
  #header-image{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  #header-paragraph{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
  #header-h1{
    font-size: 60px;
  }
  #header-links{
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.2s;
  }
  #header-links:hover{
    color: #021f3b;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #ffcab1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff8248, 0 0 4px #ff8248,0 0 80px #ff8248;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 9px;
  }
  #header-links:active{
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  #body-link-row{
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.2s;
  }
  #body-link-row:hover{
    color: #021f3b;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #ffcab1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff8248, 0 0 4px #ff8248,0 0 80px #ff8248;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 9px;
  }
  #main-footer{
    margin-top: 510px;
    color: white;
    min-height: 10vh;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  #footer{
    margin-left: 1000px;
    background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.137);
  }
  
  body{
  margin:0;
  color:#6a6f8c;
  background-image: url('images/bg.png');
  font:600 16px/18px 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  }
  *,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box}
  .clearfix:after,.clearfix:before{content:'';display:table}
  .clearfix:after{clear:both;display:block}
  a{color:inherit;text-decoration:none}
  
  .login-wrap{
  width:100%;
  margin:auto;
  max-width:525px;
  min-height:670px;
  position:relative;
  
  box-shadow:0 12px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.19);
  }
  .login-html{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  padding:90px 70px 50px 70px;
  background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  .login-html .sign-in-htm,
  .login-html .sign-up-htm{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility:hidden;
  transition:all .4s linear;
  }
  .login-html .sign-in,
  .login-html .sign-up,
  .login-form .group .check{
  display:none;
  }
  .login-html .tab,
  .login-form .group .label,
  .login-form .group .button{
  text-transform:uppercase;
  }
  .login-html .tab{
  font-size:22px;
  margin-right:15px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  margin:0 15px 10px 0;
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom:2px solid transparent;
  }
  .login-html .sign-in:checked + .tab,
  .login-html .sign-up:checked + .tab{
  color:#fff;
  border-color:#ff8248;
  }
  .login-form{
  min-height:345px;
  position:relative;
  perspective:1000px;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  }
  .login-form .group{
  margin-bottom:15px;
  }
  .login-form .group .label,
  .login-form .group .input,
  .login-form .group .button{
  width:100%;
  color:#fff;
  display:block;
  }
  .login-form .group .input,
  .login-form .group .button{
  border:none;
  padding:15px 20px;
  border-radius:25px;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  }
  .login-form .group input[data-type="password"]{
  text-security:circle;
  -webkit-text-security:circle;
  }
  .login-form .group .label{
  color:#aaa;
  font-size:12px;
  }
  .login-form .group .button{
  background:#ff8248;
  }
  .login-form .group label .icon{
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  border-radius:2px;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  }
  .login-form .group label .icon:before,
  .login-form .group label .icon:after{
  content:'';
  width:10px;
  height:2px;
  background:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  transition:all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
  .login-form .group label .icon:before{
  left:3px;
  width:5px;
  bottom:6px;
  transform:scale(0) rotate(0);
  }
  .login-form .group label .icon:after{
  top:6px;
  right:0;
  transform:scale(0) rotate(0);
  }
  .login-form .group .check:checked + label{
  color:#fff;
  }
  .login-form .group .check:checked + label .icon{
  background:#ff8248;
  }
  .login-form .group .check:checked + label .icon:before{
  transform:scale(1) rotate(45deg);
  }
  .login-form .group .check:checked + label .icon:after{
  transform:scale(1) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .login-html .sign-in:checked + .tab + .sign-up + .tab + .login-form .sign-in-htm{
  transform:rotate(0);
  }
  .login-html .sign-up:checked + .tab + .login-form .sign-up-htm{
  transform:rotate(0);
  }
  
  .hr{
  height:2px;
  margin:60px 0 50px 0;
  background:rgba(255, 227, 208, 0.2);
  }
  .foot-lnk{
  text-align:center;
  }
 
  /* Remy function*/
  @function remy($value) {
  @return ($value / 16px) * 1rem;
  }
  
  body {
  font: 100% / 1.414 "Open Sans", "Roboto", arial, sans-serif;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  }
  a,
  [type="submit"] {transition: all .25s ease-in;}
  .signup__container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: remy(800px);
  height: remy(480px);
  border-radius: remy(3px);
  box-shadow: 0px remy(3px) remy(7px) rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  }
  .signup__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.76);
  }
  .container__child {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  }
  .signup__thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  background: url(http://ultraimg.com/images/spectre-login.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
  }
  .thumbnail__logo,
  .thumbnail__content,
  .thumbnail__links {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  }
  .thumbnail__logo {align-self: flex-start;}
  .logo__shape {fill: #fff;}
  .logo__text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: .8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  }
  .thumbnail__content {align-self: center;}
  h1,
  h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  }
  .heading--primary {font-size: 1.999rem;}
  .heading--secondary {font-size: 1.414rem;}
  .thumbnail__links {
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  }
  .thumbnail__links a {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  &:focus,
  &:hover {color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);}
  }
  .signup__form {
  padding: 2.5rem;
  background: #fafafa;
  }
  label {
  font-size: .85rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ccc;
  }
  .form-control {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  &:focus {border-color: #111;}
  }
  [type="text"] {color: #111;}
  [type="password"] {color: #111;}
  .btn--form {
  padding: .5rem 2.5rem;
  font-size: .95rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  background: #111;
  border-radius: remy(35px);
  &:focus,
  &:hover {background: lighten(#111, 13%);}
  }
  .signup__link {
  font-size: .8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #999;
  &:focus,
  &:hover {color: darken(#999, 13%);}
  }
  #signup-button{
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: #fd5e19;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.2s;
  }
  
  #signup-button:hover{
    color: #021f3b;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #ffcab1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff8248, 0 0 4px #ff8248,0 0 80px #ff8248;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 9px;
  }
```

I was trying to follow this tutorial -> [Django Authentication System] https://youtu.be/mOS0L5Lb2u0
And everything was working great, until he pasted the code (21:26 seconds) and it was working for him but I kept getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the server error it seems you haven't added the register URL in your urls.py  file. Try to comment it out and see if the code runs but I'm sure it will throw another error for the login URL and for the logout URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a URL for **register** since you have this

```
<a href="{% url '**register**' %}" class="btn" style="color: white;
background-color: #fd5e14;"type="submit" id="header-links"> Create
Account </a>
```

So, add a URL for **register** like this

```
 urlpatterns = [
         path('', views.home, name='home'),
         path('register', views.register, name='register'), # <-------  add this
  ]
```

Similarly, you may need to add URLs for **login, profile**, etc

Answer (score -1):

The problem is on urls.py file. You haven't registered 'register', 'login', etc, they are not valid url names because don't exist.

This is the file urls.py on the tutorial your are following:

https://github.com/desphixs/django-authentication-system/blob/master/authsysproject/users/urls.py

Look at the difference with yours.